# getItemLayout in FlatList passing index -1 on first render

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am implementing a `FlatList` with `initialScrollIndex` and `getItemLayout`. However, every time my app starts up, it renders the first elements somehow and then jumps to the actual `initialScrollIndex`. This means that the actual performance boost that I am supposed to get, isn't working.

When checking the `getItemLayout` function I can see that when it renders the first index that is passed is `-1` instead of the `initialScrollIndex, thus throwing an error and breaking. The other random indexes are passed until`initialScrollIndex` is passed.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

FlatList:

```
renderMonthPerMonth() {
const data = this.deriveMonthPerMonthDataFromProps();
const initialScrollIndex = this.deriveInitialScrollIndex();

return (
  <FlatList
    data={data}
    ref={'flatlist'}
    initialNumToRender={3}
    onLayout={this.onLayout} 
    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    initialScrollIndex={initialScrollIndex}
    renderItem={this.renderOneMonthPerMonth}
    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderListHeader}
    keyExtractor={el => `${el.monthName}-monthPerMonth`}
    onScrollBeginDrag={() => this.onExpandMenu('scroll')}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderItemSeparator}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooterComponent}
  />
);
}
```

getItemLayout:

```
getItemLayout(data, index) {
const monthAsNumber = moment().month(data[index].monthName).format('M')-1;

const SEPARATOR_HEIGHT = 25;
const MONTH_NAME_CONTAINER_HEIGHT = 55;

const ONE_DAY_HEIGHT = (((width-40)/7)/1.1);
const WEEKS_IN_MONTH = this.weeksInMonth(moment().format('YYYY'), monthAsNumber);

// define oneMonthHeight using weeksInMonth method
const oneMonthHeight = (ONE_DAY_HEIGHT * WEEKS_IN_MONTH) + (MONTH_NAME_CONTAINER_HEIGHT + SEPARATOR_HEIGHT);

return {
  length: oneMonthHeight,
  offset: oneMonthHeight * index,
  index,
}
}
```

Console:

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried removing initialNumToRender and check again.

Comment: initialNumToRender ia critical for performance

Comment: Yeah I know but just a small hunch.

Comment: No, It doesn't change anything. I have tried on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I have a suspicion the problem is in the `renderItem` prop and subsequently the `renderOneMonthPerMonth()` method.

Referring to the [FlatList docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist):

> This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow-equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem function depends on is passed as a prop (e.g. extraData) that is not === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state.

and

> renderItem({ item: Object, index: number, separators: { highlight: Function, unhighlight: Function, updateProps: Function(select: string, newProps: Object) } }) => ?React.Element

Having `this.deriveMonthPerMonthDataFromProps()` may not be Pure (depending on that prop, I cannot see it).

1. Try fetching all the data and assigning to a const outside the renderItem method that is passed. Alternatively if this data is pure and not changing you can skip this step.
2. The next two are probably the crux of the issue: create a render function resembling this:

```
      const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
        return <DummyComponent item={item} index={index} /> // item and index are not necessarry just demonstrating
      }
```

3. Ensure you have a keyExtractor returning unique identifier. Else this will error in a similar manner to your issue. Try the below as a sanity check

```
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

If the above is not the issue you also need to ensure that your data prop on your Flatlist is an **array** and not an **Object** or other data structure as explained in the [data](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#data) section of the Flatlist docs.

If your data is of type object and you don't rely on the keys to access specific pieces of data in other methods, you can change the initial data to be an array of objects like so:

```
[
  { ...monthOneData },
  { ...monthTwoData },
  { ...monthThreeData }
]
```

Or, if you want to keep the original data as an object you can convert it to an array of keys by using

```
Object.keys(this.state.data)
```

Then in your FlatList you could do something like this:

```
<FlatList
  data={Object.keys(this.state.data)}
  renderItem={({item}) => 
    <DummyComponent month={this.state.data[item].month} /> // item is now the key value of the objects (almost like a look up table)
    // also not having curly braces implies an implicit return in this case
  }
/>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried all of this and it didnt work. `this.deriveMonthPerMonthDataFromProps()` is pure, I even mapped it to `this.state` on `componentDidMount()`. I think this might be a bug?